# UITableView created programmatically in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have difficulties to create a tableView programmatically in a ViewController. I have this code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let myTV = UITableView()
var myNavBar: UINavigationBar!
var arrayNumbers = [3, 42, 56, 55, 73]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let margins = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide
    myNavBar = UINavigationBar()
    myNavBar.barStyle = .black
    myNavBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let myNavTitle = UINavigationItem(title: "Home")

    myNavBar.setItems([myNavTitle], animated: true)

    self.view.addSubview(myNavBar)

    myNavBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    myNavBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    myNavBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    showContent()
}

func showContent() {

    if arrayNumbers.count > 0 {
        self.view.addSubview(myTV)
        myTV.backgroundColor = .clear
        myTV.separatorStyle = .none
        myTV.dataSource = self
        myTV.delegate = self
        myTV.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
        myTV.reloadData()
        myTV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false



        myTV.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myNavBar.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        myTV.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myNavBar.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        myTV.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myNavBar.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}


}


  extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayNumbers.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = myTV.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(arrayNumbers[indexPath.row])"
    return cell
}
}


extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("You have selected \(arrayNumbers[indexPath.row]).")
}
}
```

On the screen of my iPhone 8 I see just the NavigationBar.

On the debug console I have this messages:

> 2019-10-12 10:43:15.730330+0200 My TableView[3922:2655506] Creating
>   client/daemon connection: CEC5AA51-ECC7-4F7D-A540-A850CB470703
>   2019-10-12 10:43:15.760091+0200 My TableView[3922:2655506] Got the
>   query meta data reply for: com.apple.MobileAsset.MacinTalkVoiceAssets,
>   response: 0 2019-10-12 10:43:15.762379+0200 My TableView[3922:2655506]
>   Consumed extension 2019-10-12 10:43:15.768843+0200 My
>   TableView[3922:2655506] Got the query meta data reply for:
>   com.apple.MobileAsset.MacinTalkVoiceAssets, response: 0 2019-10-12
>   10:43:17.013095+0200 My TableView[3922:2655311] [AXRuntimeCommon]
>   Unknown client: My TableView

Comment: You haven't set a bottom constraint for your table view so its height will be 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You disn't set the `Bottom Anchor` or `Height Anchor` for the `UITableView` named **myTV**

Write this code in your `showContent()` function & try again

```
    myTV.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    myTV.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myNavBar.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    myTV.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    myTV.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much! !